# Way to not duplicate Excel formula in IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have a relatively computationally expensive and long function *f(.)* dragged down a column.  If the result of the function in any given cell is an arbitrary value *x*, then I want the value of the cell to be the arbitrary value *y*.  Of course, this can be accomplished quite easily like this

```
=IF(f(.) = x, y, f(.))
```

I have two questions:

1. If the output is *x* for a cell, will Excel compute *f* two times because of the IF statement?
2. If so, is there a way to make the implementation more efficient both visually and computationally without helper columns?

Thank you.

Comment: If your version of Excel supports it, use `LET`.

Comment: To expand on BigBen's comment: in this case, ```=LET(F, f(.), IF(x=F,y,F))```

Comment: No, if the output is x then the formula will only be calculated once.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we may use substitute like

```
=SUBSTITUTE(f(.),x,y)*1
```

Then it should not calculate the inner function twice.

[image]

Comment: In case of text functions, no need to multiply by 1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. Say the function is:

```
A1+A3+A5+A7+A11+A13
```

and our `IF()` is:

```
=IF(A1+A3+A5+A7+A11+A13=99,"top",A1+A3+A5+A7+A11+A13)
```

To avoid repetition:

```
=LET(f,A1+A3+A5+A7+A11+A13,IF(f=99,"top",f))
```